# How to find the URL of a blog item in blog category view

Tags: overrides, category-blog

I am doing a category blog override.  As part of that I require the blog item URL.  Not the current URL, which I can get, the read more URL of the blog.

I tried to create a JLayout override, and strip everything except the URL, but that hasn't worked.  I get the error:

**Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

I'm not much of a programmer, but I'm a bit confused as to why this won't work but it will for a normal JLayout.  All I did was remove some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better way of doing this.

```
<a href="
    <?php echo 
        JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, 
                    $this->item->catid, $this->item->language)); 
    ?>
">Learn More</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another even better way of doing this.

```
<?php echo $item->link; ?>
```

Comment: Lol...nicely refactored

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to do this.  There is probably a MUCH better way, but this is how I did it.

## Create my JLayout override

First of all, I went to my Joomla! site.  I went to **layouts/joomla/content/blog_style_default_item_title.php**

I resaved that file in a new location:

**templates/YOUR_TEMPLATES_NAME/html/layouts/joomla/content/**

I **renamed** it, blog_style_default_URL.php

## Edit the new JLayout override

Now, I can go into this new layout file, strip the `<h2>` and the `<a>` leaving just the URL.  In this instance, I know that I will always have linked titles, so I can remove the `if` statement too.  I could probably strip everything and just leave:

```
<?php echo 
    JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($displayData->slug, 
    $displayData->catid, $displayData->language)); 
?>
```

## Create my HTML override, and call my JLayout

Now I create my **HTML override** (I won't cover how to do that), in my blog override, blog_item.php, I call the layout.  `JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_url', $this->item);`

That gives me my url, but it only provides `index.php/21-my-blog-item.php`

## Find the Base URL and append it

We need the base url too.  So I use:

```
<?php echo 
    $url . JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_url', 
    $this->item); 
?>
```

## Remove the trailing slash (if included)

Now I have my url, but I have two slashes.  Doh.

www.mywebsite.com//index.php/21-my-blog-item.php

So I used:

```
<?php 
  // Get the base URL & trip the slash
  $url            = JURI::base();
  $url            = $url = rtrim($url, '/');
?>
```

## Final code

Now in my url I have:

```
<a href="
    <?php echo 
        $url . JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_url', 
        $this->item); 
    ?>" 
</a>
```